# How to oversample instances in a data set in R

Tags: r, dataset, weka

I have a data set with 20 classes, and it has a pretty non-uniform distribution. Is there any functionality in R that allows us to balance the data set (weighted perhaps)?

I want to use the balanced data with Weka for classification. Since my class distribution is skewed, I am hoping to get better results if there's no single majority class.

I have tried to use the SMOTE filter and Resample filter but they don't quite do what I want. 
I dont want any instances to be removed, repetition is fine.

Comment: Not sure who voted this down, but I think it's because a lot more information is needed to answer your question. Try str() or dput() for your data to give people an idea of what exactly you have to work with.

Comment: Also, your question may be more suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding in your terminology.  Your question's title refers to sampling, and yet the question text involves weighting.

To clarify:

With sampling, you either have fewer, the same, or more instances than in the original set; the unique membership of a sample can be either a strict subset of the original set or can be identical to the original set (with replacement - i.e., duplicates).

By weighting, you simply adjust weights that may be used for some further purpose (e.g. sampling, machine learning) to address or impose some (im)balance relative to a uniform weighting.

I believe that you are referring to weighting, but the same answer should work in both cases.  If the total # of observations is `N` and the frequency of each class is an element of the 20-long vector `freq` (e.g. the count of items in class 1 is `freq[1]*N`), then simply use a weight vector of `1/freq` to normalize the weights.  You can scale it by some constant, e.g. `N`, though it wouldn't matter.  In case any frequency is 0 or very close to it, you might address this by using a vector of smoothed counts (e.g. Good-Turing smoothing).

As a result, each set will have an equal proportion of the total weight.

Comment: This isn't a criticism, since the OP is so vague, but I would add that in some statistical learning settings (eg bagging, random forests) a similar effect *is* sometimes achieved via sampling. For instance, taking a balanced subsample (with or w/out replacement) of each class to build each tree in the forest.

Comment: That is correct; it also extends to pretty much all statistical learning methods (after all, a training set is a sample ;)).  It would be easier if the OP had allowed for sampling with replacement, but no instances are to be dropped, so one needs to over-weight the samples (for the modeling) or over-sample.  In either scenario, a weighting scheme seems necessary.